# Python list slicing

Tags: python, list

I'm not able understand what to do here. Can someone help.

I've a few lists:

```
array = [7,8,2,3,4,10,5,6,7,10,8,9,10,4,5,12,13,14,1,2,15,16,17]
slice = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22]
intervals = [12, 17, 22]
output = []
intermediate = []
```

`slice` is a list of indices I need to get from slicing `array`. `interval` is a list of indices used to stop the slicing when `slice[i] is interval[j]` where i and j are looping variables.
I need to form a list of lists from `array` based on `slice` and `intervals` based on the condition that when `slice[i] is not interval[j]`

```
intermediate =intermediate + array[slice[i]:slice[i+1]+1]
```

here in my case:

when `slice[i]` and `interval[j]` are equal for value 12. So I need to form a list of lists from `array`

```
intermediate = array[slice[0]:slice[0+1]+1] + array[slice[2]:slice[2+1]+1] + array[slice[4]:slice[4+1]+1]
```

which is

```
intermediate  = array[2:(4+1)] + array[6:(8+1)] + array[10:(12+1)]
```

and when `slice[i] is interval[j]` `output = output + intermediate` and the slicing is continued.

```
output = output + [intermediate]
```

which is

```
output = output + [array[2:(4+1)] + array[6:(8+1)] + array[10:(12+1)]]
```

now the next value in interval is 17 so till we have 17 in `slice` we form another list from `array[slice[6]:slice[6+1]+1]` and add this to the output. This continues.

The final output should be:

```
output = [array[slice[0]:slice[0+1]+1] + array[slice[2]:slice[2+1]+1] + array[slice[4]:slice[4+1]+1] , array[slice[6]:slice[6+1]+1], array[slice[8]:slice[8+1]+1]]
```

which is

```
output = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
```

Comment: what if the slice contains odd elements between two intervals? should the last index be discarded since it is a paired slicing?

Comment: slice is strictly even.

Comment: `slice` is a [reserved python keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#slice). don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @RickTeachey `slice` is only the name of a builtin class, but I strongly agree not to use it and other builtin names.  `import keyword; print(keyword.kwlist)` lists reserved keywords.  `import builtins; print(dir(builtins))` (py3) lists all builtin names.

Comment: hey guys, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy whoops, got the terminology wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward solution:

```
array_ = [7,8,2,3,4,10,5,6,7,10,8,9,10,4,5,12,13,14,1,2,15,16,17]
slice_ = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22]
intervals = [12, 17, 22]
output = []
intermediate = []

for i in range(0, len(slice_), 2):
    intermediate.extend(array_[slice_[i]:slice_[i+1]+1])
    if slice_[i+1] in intervals:
        output.append(intermediate)
        intermediate = []

print output
# [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
```

I have changed some variable names to avoid conflicts.
On large data, you may convert `intervals` to a set.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution which goes through the index once and dynamically check if the index is within the intervals and append the sliced results to a list accordingly:

```
def slicing(array, index, stops, sliced):
    # if the length of index is smaller than two, stop
    if len(index) < 2:
        return 

    # if the first element of the index in the intervals, create a new list in the result 
    # accordingly and move one index forward
    elif index[0] in stops:
        if len(index) >= 3:
            sliced += [[]]
            slicing(array, index[1:], stops, sliced)

    # if the second element of the index is in the intervals, append the slice to the last
    # element of the list, create a new sublist and move two indexes forward accordingly
    elif index[1] in stops:
        sliced[-1] += array[index[0]:(index[1]+1)]
        if len(index) >= 4:
            sliced += [[]]
            slicing(array, index[2:], stops, sliced)

    # append the new slice to the last element of the result list and move two index 
    # forward if none of the above conditions satisfied:       
    else:
        sliced[-1] += array[index[0]:(index[1]+1)]
        slicing(array, index[2:], stops, sliced)

sliced = [[]]
slicing(array, slice_, intervals, sliced)

sliced
# [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
```

*Data*:

```
array = [7,8,2,3,4,10,5,6,7,10,8,9,10,4,5,12,13,14,1,2,15,16,17]
slice_ = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 20, 22]
intervals = [12, 17, 22]
```